Windows 11 - Screen goes black for an instant when changing volume or brightness when Minecraft is in Fullscreen and it's using integrated GPU
When Minecraft is in Fullscreen and running in the integrated graphics and I change the volume or the brightness, the screen goes black for about half a second, after that, the screen looks normal (and the game runs slightly worse even in the title screen) while the animation of changing volume or brightness of Windows is on the screen, after the animation ends, the screen goes black again for about the same time and the screen returns to the normal. This issue only happens when using the integrated intel graphics and only on Minecraft. It also happens when a notification of windows is displayed on the screen and when switching between the game and the desktop. I've tried different versions of minecraft (vanilla and modded). The game runs normally when its in windowed mode.
System:

Acer Nitro 5 AN515-58
Intel I5 12500H
Nvidia RTX 3050

Things i've tried:

Updated intel and nvidia drivers
Running the game in borderless screen (with mods; the issue only happens when the window surpasses and hide the windows taskbar)
Running the game in compatibility mode
Disabling fullscreen optimizations (on the java executable and in windows)
Turning off V-sync
Reinstall Windows


Verify that Minecraft is using the Nvidia dGPU card instead of the Intel iGPU. Running an application like Minecraft in comparability mode does absolutely nothing, any application that runs on Windows 11, gains absolutely nothing from compatibility mode. If this issue only happens while using the less powerful intel GPU the simplest solution is to stop using it to play Minecraft.

@John I downloaded and updated the BIOS from Acer official product support website but didn't work. Thanks anyway

@Ramhound The only reason I want to use the Intel GPU is cause I want the fans to be as quiet as possible. It's not that big of a problem either. Thanks anyway.
